# How to split multi-dimensional arrays based on the unique indices of another array?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two `torch` tensors `a` and `b`:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0) # for reproducibility

a = torch.rand(size = (5, 10, 1))
b = torch.tensor([3, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2])
```

I want to split the 2nd dimension of `a` (which is dim = 1 in the `Python` language) based on the unique values in `b`.

What I have tried so far:

```
# find the unique values and unique indices of b
unique_values, unique_indices = torch.unique(b, return_inverse = True)

# split a in where dim = 1, based on unique indices
l = torch.tensor_split(a, unique_indices, dim = 1)
```

I was expecting `l` to be a list of **n** number of tensors where **n** is the number of unique values in `b`. I was also expecting the tensors to have the shape (5, **number of elements corresponding to unique_values**, 1).

However, I get the following:

```
print(l)

(tensor([[[0.8198],
         [0.9971],
         [0.6984]],

        [[0.7262],
         [0.7011],
         [0.2038]],

        [[0.1147],
         [0.3168],
         [0.6965]],

        [[0.0340],
         [0.9442],
         [0.8802]],

        [[0.6833],
         [0.7529],
         [0.8579]]]), tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1)), tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1)), tensor([[[0.9971],
         [0.6984],
         [0.5675]],

        [[0.7011],
         [0.2038],
         [0.6511]],

        [[0.3168],
         [0.6965],
         [0.9143]],

        [[0.9442],
         [0.8802],
         [0.0012]],

        [[0.7529],
         [0.8579],
         [0.6870]]]), tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1)), tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1)), tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1)), tensor([[[0.8198],
         [0.9971]],

        [[0.7262],
         [0.7011]],

        [[0.1147],
         [0.3168]],

        [[0.0340],
         [0.9442]],

        [[0.6833],
         [0.7529]]]), tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1)), tensor([[[0.9971]],

        [[0.7011]],

        [[0.3168]],

        [[0.9442]],

        [[0.7529]]]), tensor([[[0.6984],
         [0.5675],
         [0.8352],
         [0.2056],
         [0.5932],
         [0.1123],
         [0.1535],
         [0.2417]],

        [[0.2038],
         [0.6511],
         [0.7745],
         [0.4369],
         [0.5191],
         [0.6159],
         [0.8102],
         [0.9801]],

        [[0.6965],
         [0.9143],
         [0.9351],
         [0.9412],
         [0.5995],
         [0.0652],
         [0.5460],
         [0.1872]],

        [[0.8802],
         [0.0012],
         [0.5936],
         [0.4158],
         [0.4177],
         [0.2711],
         [0.6923],
         [0.2038]],

        [[0.8579],
         [0.6870],
         [0.0051],
         [0.1757],
         [0.7497],
         [0.6047],
         [0.1100],
         [0.2121]]]))
```

Why do I get empty tensors like `tensor([], size=(5, 0, 1))` and how would I achieve what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description of the desired result:

> I was also expecting the tensors to have the shape `(5, number of elements corresponding to unique_values, 1)`.

I believe you are looking for the *count* (or *frequency*) of unique values. If you want to keep using `torch.unique`, then you can provide the `return_counts` argument combined with a call to [`torch.cumsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cumsum.html).

Something like this should work:

```
>>> indices = torch.cumsum(counts, dim=0)
>>> splits = torch.tensor_split(a, indices[:-1], dim = 1)
```

Let's have a look:

```
>>> for x in splits:
...     print(x.shape)
torch.Size([5, 1, 1])
torch.Size([5, 3, 1])
torch.Size([5, 2, 1])
torch.Size([5, 3, 1])
torch.Size([5, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `index_select` method?

You have correclty obtained your unique **values** in `unique_values`.

Now what you need to do is:

```
l = a.index_select(1, unique_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the correct way to do this is by using the scatter function from `torch_scatter`.

```
scatter(a, unique_indices, dim=1, reduce='min')
```

This function goes over the array a, and in the ith entry of the output tensor, it puts the minimum of elements that were mapped to the ith entry of the input tensor.

Note: using 'min' as a reduction is arbitrary. You might want the maximum, mean or something else!

Note 2: regarding the other answers, Ivan's answer is incorrect since torch does not promise to keep the ordering of the entries! (to have a chance of it working, one needs to pass the `sorted=False` argument). as for guibs35's answer, it is using the  mapping incorrectly, the output is something the size of the original tensor!